# Merge two data.frames in R

Tags: r

I m trying to merge 2 files with postal code in R.

One file has financial info by state and postal codes (file `a`) and the other file has postal code, country, activities, and dates(file `b`). Some of the postal code in the first file `a` are not present in the second file `b`.

So I m trying to merge all the postal codes of file `b` with that of file `a` without losing any information on my file `a`.

My code is:

```
merge(a, b, by="posta code", all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: Clearly a duplicate (flagged). For future reference, please share a reproducible example. In this case, paste the output of `dput(head(a))` and `dput(head(b))`

Comment: And, what's the question ? ^^'

Answer (score 0):

If you like SQL, you could try following code:

```
library(sqldf)
combined = sqldf("SELECT a.*, country, activity, date
                  FROM a JOIN b
                  using(`postal code`)")
```